# Returning errors in nested then and promises ExpressJS/NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, sequelize.js

I am having a bit of confusion on returning error from function calls.
For example purpose, I am using sequelizeJS to illustrate the point.
Normally:

**First.Ctrl**

```
var second_ctrl = require( '../ctrl/second');
testCode : function(req, res, next){
    return second_ctrl.getData()
          .then(function(resultData){
                res.json(resultData);
          })
          .catch(function(error){
                res.json(error)
          })
}
```

**Second.Ctrl**

```
getData : function(){
    return models.Data.findAll()              
}
```

Any error in the getData findAll would go to catch block of first_ctrl. But if I have to do some manipulations like:

**Second.Ctrl - Manipulation**

```
getData : function(){
    return models.Data.findAll()
          .then(function(result){
                if(result == null)
                   throw new Error ('No data found');
                return  result;
          })
          .catch(function(error){
                throw error;
                //return error
          })
}
```

I have tried using throw error, return error and removing the inner catch block but in both cases - the execution goes to then block in first_ctrl with resultData having received the error object.

What is the best practice for this kind of situations as these nested call can go even deeper (first_ctrl -> second_ctrl -> third_ctrl)

Let me know. Looking forward to your thoughts

Comment: are you sure you landed in the then block when you throw? Expected behavior is like your example and you should end up in your outer catch block (you don't even need the inner catch block if you want to always catch in the outer block).

Comment: even I tried removing the inner catch block but I am ending in the then block of first_ctrl.

Comment: @adeneo: as I know for promises, I have to use a promise library like q or bluebird. Is this not possible without these like normally. If possible, please let me know how I can by a snippet.

Comment: I don't think I quite got it. You throw an error, and end up in the first catch block, but you don't end up in the second chained catch block, because the chain is restored. Throwing inside the catch block should work as far as I can tell.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/byt9b6oz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer yet but it hopefully helps you to get on track.

Your core idea is right. Following code works:

```
const myPromise = Promise.reject(new Error('some error'))
  .then(res => console.log('inner then'))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('inner err');
    throw err
  })
  .then(res => console.log('outer then'))
  .catch(err => console.log('outer err'));
// logs:
//   inner err
//   outer err
```

So following things i can imagine are possible the cause of our problem:

- you are in the outer catch block without noticing it (you call res.json() in there as well as in your outer then - how do you know which one is getting called)
- you are using a bugged promise library.

Hope this helps at least a bit.

Comment: I am not using any promise library neither I am creating any promise object in second_ctrl. It is as is it mentioned above. I guess that is the cause? I have to use a promise library. Right?

Comment: What does models.Data.findAll() return other than a promise? It sure returns something thenable or your then block wouldn't be called either